# How to satisfy "[FLAKE8 W605] invalid escape sequence '\.'" and string format in the mean time?

Tags: python, regex, flake8

I have an issue in python. My original regex expression is:

```
f"regex(metrics_api_failure\.prod\.[\w_]+\.{method_name}\.\d+\.\d+\.[\w_]+\.[\w_]+\.sum\.60)"
```

(`method_name` is a local variable) and I got a lint warning:

```
"[FLAKE8 W605] invalid escape sequence '\.'Arc(W605)"
```

Which looks like recommends me to use `r` as the regex prefix. But if I do:

```
r"regex(metrics_api_failure\.prod\.[\w_]+\.{method_name}\.\d+\.\d+\.[\w_]+\.[\w_]+\.sum\.60)"
```

The `{method_name}` becomes the string type rather than a passed in variable.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this dilemma?

Comment: "Does anyone have an idea how to solve this dilemma?" Did you try using both prefixes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pass in the expression:

```
r"regex(metrics_api_failure\.prod\.[\w_]+\." + method_name + r"\.\d+\.\d+\.[\w_]+\.[\w_]+\.sum\.60)"
```

Essentially, use Python string concatenation to accomplish the same thing that you were doing with the brackets. Then, `r""` type string escaping should work.

or use a raw format string:

```
rf"regex(metrics_api_failure\.prod\.[\w_]+\.{method_name}\.\d+\.\d+\.[\w_]+\.[\w_]+\.sum\.60)"
```